# What is the name of this IntelliJ feature?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to add a hotkey to the feature(toggle view/hide) on the image below, but do not know its name.

So on a git change IntelliJ shows a green(other colours) marker, so I click on it to view it. I want to add a hotkey so I don't have to use the mouse

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ, you could use `Next Change` and `Previous Change` to achieve the above feature without using a mouse.

1. First open a file with Git changes.
2. Follow the attached image. (I have provided instruction for mac, but it should be the same on other OS as well)

Important: If the file that you opened does not have git changes, this won't be available on `Navigate` tab.

Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks.

[image]